# Invalid argument during changing ownership

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, ownership

I want to change ownership of file. I made this command as root:

```
chown test:test make_import.py
```

I recieved this error:

```
chown: changing ownership of ‘make_import.py’: Invalid argument
```

I couldn't find clear solution in web.
Thanks for any hint.

Comment: The file is on a local filesystem?

Comment: is the user `test` present on the system?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this file is on a remote/mounted filesystem. Can you check that with either "df" or "mount" command? If it is remote filesystem then possibly the mount options disallow changing the file.